# How to continuously check if there is a change within the Database of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an multiplayer pen and paper S.O.S game and I found online some people were able to something similar using Firebase. I've hit a road block and can't find a proper solution for it.

How my app works currently the player 1 is able to create a new game and enters the game activity the game code is displayed. Player 2 can join the game by typing the game code that was generated and join the game, his/her information is inserted to the database. My problem is that player 1 , while waiting in the game activity, has no way to know if player 2 has join the game.

What I want to know if there is a way to check the database continuously while player 1 is waiting for player 2 to join. I tried ondatachange but I found that method is only triggered once, and I need a method to check/triggered continuously or at least check if there a change within database if player 2 has joined the game.

```
Firebase Database Structure
Before Player 2 Joins
----
   Game
   |
   -------(Game Code)
               |
               ---------(Game Code)
               ---------(Player 1 Details)

After Player 2 Joins
----
   Game
   |
   -------(Game Code)
               |
               ---------(Game Code)
               ---------(Player 1 Details)
               ---------(Player 2 Details)
```

Comment: Are you using Firestore ore RealtimeDatabase? In both situations you can listen for changes but the API is different.

Comment: I'm using Firebase Real-time-Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Realtime Database, not Firestore. You can learn more by reading this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) page.

What you are looking for is something like:

```
val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        val post = dataSnapshot.getValue<Post>()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        // ...
    }
}
postReference.addValueEventListener(postListener)
```

Where you will have your listener do something like:

```
postReference.child("Game").child("Game Code").addValueEventListener(postListener)
```

And check in your listener if player 2 exists. The listener code will only get triggered when something changes on the cloud side of Firebase. So when a new player is added your listener code will be called.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've solved the problem a while ago, but the solution I found is something similar. What I used is addValueEventListener and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

there is snapshotListeners for the database, check out official documentation from :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#kotlin+ktx

or watch this youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kre5cmoR8Q

happy hacking..